# XAML control that supports data binding except listview or listbox

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps

Is there any XAML control that supports data binding except listview or listbox. I am developing an application using windows azure mobile services table. After retrieving the data from table I am binding the list to a listview as a small preview. When user will select any Item from the list view I want to display the details of the selected item. Which XAML control will be suitable for this task. I can use lots of TextBoxes  and assign its Text property from C# code. I dont think It is a good practice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If it's a better collection viewer you are looking for for, use a DataGrid. If you want to show more info, it's worth making another panel and showing more data there about the selected item (master detail pattern)

All XAML controls support data bindings. Use DataContext if you want children to access the binding, otherwise you can bind directly on the property.

For example, you could have a separate panel that is a Grid with a few child controls. This Grid's DataContext can be set to the DataGrid's SelectedItem, then it's child controls can easily bind to the item's properties.

Comment: DataGrid is not Supported in Windows app Project

Comment: I see, look up tutorials for the master-detail pattern in XAMl